# About list slicing in Python

Tags: python, list

I have learned `Python` for about 4 months, I thought I know every basics now. But currently I accidently tried a simple python expression, and the result is out of my expectation.

for example:

```
test = [1,2,3,4]

test[0:-1:-1]
```

and the result is an empty list(`[]`).

However, my expected result is `[3,2,1]` for `"test[::-1]"` will output `"[4,3,2,1]"`.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Perhaps this can provide insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41783307/understanding-negative-steps-in-list-slicing

Comment: Besides reading the prev. post - you could try this: ``` test[-2::-1]``` ->
[3, 2, 1]

Comment: "Stepping backwards from the first index to the last"… how should that produce any output?